# jQuery.data(): set values from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have some images that I create using data from a MySQL database. The data in the database are a title and a description. This is not visible on the website until a user clicks the image. Javascript then loads it in some other place, not anywhere near my image.

My problem is the accessing of this data. I create my elements in PHP with this structure:

```
<div class="image-container">
    <img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" alt="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
    <div class="title" style="display: none;"><?php echo $title; ?></div>
    <div class="description" style="display: none;"><?php echo $description; ?></div>
</div>
```

When the image is clicked, I call for the data like this:

```
$('.image-container').click(handle_image_click);

function handle_image_click(e) {
    var title = jQuery(e.currentTarget).find('.title').html();
    var description = jQuery(e.currentTarget).find('.description').html();
    (...)
}
```

Allthough this works, I don't find this a very 'clean' solution. It requires me having to hide div elements and 'store' data in them. I know you can store data to elements in jQuery using the following code:

```
$('#myElement').data('someName', 'someValue');
```

Now my question is: is there any way to not have to create the div elements in php (as seen in code block 1), but directly add the description and title to the 'data'-property of the element, ready to be fetched by javascript/jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the [data-*](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5) [html5 attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) to store data

```
<div class="image-container" data-title="<?php echo $title; ?>" data-description="<?php echo $description; ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" alt="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
</div>
```

then in the handler

```
$('.image-container').click(handle_image_click);

function handle_image_click(e) {
    var title = jQuery(this).data('title');
    var description = jQuery(this).data('description');
    (...)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

yes you can.. using html5 data attribute

```
  <img src="<?php echo $url; ?>" data-title="<?php echo $title; ?>" data-description="<?php echo $description; ?>" alt="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
```

and fetch it with jquery using `data()`

```
  ...
 function handle_image_click(e) {
   var title = jQuery(e.currentTarget).find('img').data('title'); //gives title
   var description= jQuery(e.currentTarget).find('img').data('description'); //gives description
 ....
```